# Docker-Compose: How to restart another service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services running, and service B is dependent on server A.

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  serviceA:
    healthcheck:
       ...
    restart: always
    ....
  serviceB:
    depends_on:
      serviceA:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    ....
```

When service A fails, it does indeed restart, as it should. However, service B does not automatically restart since it doesn't exit with failure.

Is there a way to force service B to restart once service A does?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `service B does not automatically restart since it doesn't exit with failure.` Do you mean that service B exits with a success code, or that it doesn't exit at all?

Comment: It does not exit at all.

Comment: Why do you need it to?  If it's communicating with a request-oriented protocol like HTTP, new requests should reach the new container.  For something more connection-oriented it might be a good practice to automatically reconnect if the connection fails, or to exit yourself if you can't communicate.